# Windows batch copy multiple folders with name trimming

Tags: windows, batch-file, wildcard, trim

I'm trying to copy & paste several folders inside a single folder, this is meant to be a simple backup/restore process.
I can create the backup copies with the following:

```
for /d %%G in ("AppSettings\AppName version ?.?.?") do xcopy /e/h/k/c/i "%%~G" "%%~G_BACKUP"
```

I can delete them with a variation of the same using:

```
do rd /s /q "%%~G"
```

But I can't "restore" because I can't trim the "_BACKUP" from the name using the same process... the working folder name is rigid, it has to be "AppName Vesrion #.#.#" .

Any advice will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not (if original dir aren't deleted)

```
for /d %%G in ("AppSettings\AppName version ?.?.?") do xcopy /e/h/k/c/i "%%~G_BACKUP" "%%~G"
```

or

```
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /d %%G in ("AppSettings\AppName version ?.?.?_BACKUP") do (
  set "originalPath=%%G" 
  set "originalPath=!originalPath:_BACKUP=!"
  xcopy /e/h/k/c/i "%%~G" "!originalPath!"
)
EndLocal
```

*set "originalPath=!originalPath:_BACKUP=!"* will remove any ocurrence of _BACKUP from originalPath

Comment: The first solution will not work for me because the mask doesn't catch the backup folders. The second one does just what I need. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for /d %%G in ("AppSettings\AppName version ?.?.?_BACKUP") do (
  for /F "tokens=1 delims=_" %%g in ("%%~nxG") do (
    if exist "%%~dpG%%g" (
         rem next xcopy might ask Overwrite <full file path> (Yes/No/All)? 
      xcopy /e/h/k/c/i "%%~G" "%%~dpG%%g"
    ) else (
      move "%%~G" "%%g"
    )
  )
)
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%%~nxG` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

Comment: Nice idea, I tried this but the /F extension handles files only, so this solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: @LazyMonk [FOR /F command](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) can parse a (literal) text string: _a string of text will be treated just like a single line of input from a file, the string must be enclosed in double quotes (or single quotes with usebackq)_. And this is the case: `for /F "tokens=1 delims=_" %%g in ("%%~nxG") do …` does not handle any file but `"%%~nxG"` string taken from [`FOR /D` command](http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html), i.e. a _directory name_ in each iteration.

Comment: I see now what you did there. My example was simplified, I needed `%%~fG` instead of `%%~nxG` to make it work for me. And the desired action, for me, was the one you place under `else`.
Still, it works! thanx :)